# Cannot write to text file from Python

Tags: python, tkinter, text-files

This might be very simple, but I still cannot figure what is the solution. I have this code, it's a sample from a longer code.

```
radio1Value = slotchoose.get()
if radio1Value == 0:
    with open ("test2.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write ("Slot : 9 AM - 10 AM")
    slot.remove("9 AM") 
    r12.destroy()
elif radio1Value == 1:
    slot.remove("10 AM")
    with open ("test2.txt", "w") as file :
        file.write ("Slot : 10 AM - 11 AM\n")
    r13.destroy()

checkValue = doctor.get()
if checkValue == 1:
    with open ("test2.txt", "w") as file :
        file.write ("\nDoctor : Dr. Adam Ahmed")
        payment = "RM100.00"
elif checkValue == 2:
    with open ("test2.txt", "w") as file :
        file.write ("Doctor : Dr Adib Kamal")
        payment = "RM200.00"

radioValue = specialistchoose.get()

if radioValue == 1 :
    with open ("test2.txt", "w") as file :
        file.write ("\nSpecialist : Cardiology")
elif radioValue == 2:
    with open ("test2.txt", "w") as file : 
        file.write ("Specialist : Gastroenterology")
elif radioValue == 3:
    with open ("test2.txt", "w") as file : 
        file.write ("Specialist : Dermatology")
elif radioValue == "Psychiatry":
    with open ("test2.txt", "w") as file : 
        file.write("Specialist : Psychiatry")
elif radioValue == "Dentist" :
    with open ("test2.txt", "w") as file: 
        file.write("Specialist : Dentist")
```

`slotchoose`, `doctor`, and `specialistchoose` came from input from user by clicking a radiobutton and a check button. I'm trying to add a string value to `slotchoose`, `doctor`, and `specialchoose`, then save it into a text file. But the problem is every time I run it, and open the text file, `test2.txt`, it will only have the `specialistchoose` value.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you tried looking at the values before printing them to the file? Are you aware of what the `"w"` mode of open files does?

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the file every time you `open()` because that's what mode `w` does. If you want to accumulate text from several writes to the file, you need to use the append mode (`a`) instead.

Python 2 doc:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Python 3 doc:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

> mode is an optional string that specifies the mode in which the file is opened. It defaults to 'r' which means open for reading in text mode. Other common values are 'w' for writing (**truncating the file if it already exists**), 'x' for exclusive creation and **'a' for appending**